# No Firebase App '[Default] has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My app is connected to firebase and auth is working fine. However, when trying to use firestore I can't figure out this problem.

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

I am getting the above error however, I am already calling initializeApp and not sure what else to try. I am trying to get access to a collection on firestore and print it out but it gives me the error when I try to access firestore.

I have tried doing console.log(firebase.app().name) which gives the name of the app, so not sure how it is not initialised.

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  databaseURL: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
  measurementId: "****",
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = firebase.firestore()
```

My imports are

```
import "firebase/firestore"
import firebase from "firebase"
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"
```

I have tried so many different questions on here and forums but nothing has helped

Comment: Have you added 'GoogleServiceInfo.plist' in your project ?

Comment: @KishanBharda i'm only developing for Android so I don't think I need it right?

Comment: Ok, so you have to add 'GoogleService.json' in your project at yourProject/android/app.

Comment: @KishanBharda followed the docs and added that in, i'm now getting an error saying caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. Which is a step forward I think. Thank you

Comment: That may be related to firestore security rule. I think you need to modify firestore security rules.

Comment: @KishanBharda yeah that sorted it. Spent two days trying to fix this. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer ? So It helps to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Kishan above. I added the google-services.json file into the android level folder and modified both build.gradle files.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup followed step 3 here to update the build.gradle files to use google-services.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you made all the configuration correctly by following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I&t)

And just make sure that the first 2 lines at main function are (follow the same order):

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //rest of the code
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```